# PhoneGap Build not show Facebook Plugin

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins, phonegap-cli

I have added this to my config.xml:

```
<plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" spec="0.9.0">
    <param name="APP_ID" value="583461171820280" />
    <param name="APP_NAME" value="Trufes2016" />
</gap:plugin>
```

and by default my widget is:

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.phonegap.trufes2016" version="1.0.0">
```

This page https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/a5c6be90d2fcadf84d944cd4410878971d99a300/platforms/pg-build/README.md said that i will be able to see my app plugins (facebook) but show nothing.

Comment: Please **answer the following questions in your post**. Since this appears to be your first post on this subject. Is this your first hybrid App? Are you using the *Phonegap Desktop App*? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Please do not assume the answer, please read the link. Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Compare both of these codes:

```
<plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" spec="0.9.0">
    <param name="APP_ID" value="583461171820280" />
    <param name="APP_NAME" value="Trufes2016" />
</gap:plugin>
```

**AND**

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" spec="0.9.0">
    <param name="APP_ID" value="583461171820280" />
    <param name="APP_NAME" value="Trufes2016" />
</gap:plugin>
```

The real problem is you are starting you tag as "**plugin**" while your closing it like "**gap:plugin**". Try the second code and it will work for you.